# RuntimeException when closing CipherInputStream

Tags: android, openssl, cryptography, android-6.0-marshmallow

I kind of got stuck with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0407806d:RSA routines:decrypt:DATA_LEN_NOT_EQUAL_TO_MOD_LEN
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.RSA_private_decrypt(Native Method)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:274)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1440)
 at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.close(CipherInputStream.java:190)
 ...
```

It is thrown when I close the CipherInputStream on Android Marshmallow. Everything seems to work with earlier Android Versions.

What does `DATA_LEN_NOT_EQUAL_TO_MOD_LEN` mean? Why does it seem to decrypt (call to `RSA_private_decrypt`) when it should free resource handles (close)?

UPDATE:

I managed to reproduce the error with some test code. It encrypts and decrypts `"foobar"`. One time using the cipher directly and one time through a CipherInputStream (like it's done in the original app).

Everything works on android < 6 and the non-streaming code is even working on android 6.
I was able to get the streaming code to work on android 6 when I changed the explicit cipher `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` to generic `RSA`.
But I would bet that it's there for a reason ;)

```
static final String RSA_ALGO = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
//  static final String RSA_ALGO = "RSA";

private void _testCrypto2() throws Exception {
  KeyPairGenerator keyGen;
  KeyPair          keys;
  byte[]           encrypted;
  byte[]           decrypted;
  String           input;
  String           output;

  keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
  keyGen.initialize(2048);
  keys = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

  input = "foobar";

  // Plain crypto.
  encrypted = this.RSAEncrypt(input, keys.getPublic());
  output    = this.RSADecrypt(encrypted, keys.getPrivate());

  // Streaming crypto.
  encrypted = this.RSAEncryptStream(input, keys.getPublic());
  output    = this.RSADecryptStream(encrypted, keys.getPrivate());
}

public byte[] RSAEncrypt(final String plain, PublicKey _publicKey) throws Exception {
  byte[] encryptedBytes;
  Cipher cipher;

  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGO);
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _publicKey);
  encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());

  return encryptedBytes;
}

public String RSADecrypt(final byte[] encryptedBytes, PrivateKey _privateKey) throws Exception {
  Cipher cipher;
  byte[] decryptedBytes;
  String decrypted;

  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGO);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _privateKey);

  decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
  decrypted      = new String(decryptedBytes);

  return decrypted;
}

public byte[] RSAEncryptStream(final String _plain, PublicKey _publicKey) throws Exception {
  Cipher                cipher;
  InputStream           in;
  ByteArrayOutputStream out;
  int                   numBytes;
  byte                  buffer[] = new byte[0xffff];

  in     = new ByteArrayInputStream(_plain.getBytes());
  out    = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGO);
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _publicKey);

  try {
    in = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
    while ((numBytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
    }
  }
  finally {
    in.close();
  }

  return out.toByteArray();
}

public String RSADecryptStream(final byte[] _encryptedBytes, PrivateKey _privateKey) throws Exception {
  Cipher                cipher;
  InputStream           in;
  ByteArrayOutputStream out;
  int                   numBytes;
  byte                  buffer[] = new byte[0xffff];

  in     = new ByteArrayInputStream(_encryptedBytes);
  out    = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
  cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGO);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _privateKey);

  try {
    in = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
    while ((numBytes = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, numBytes);
    }
  }
  finally {
    in.close();
  }

  return new String(out.toByteArray());
}
```

However, it looks like there are two directions for a fix:

- Getting rid of the streaming for RSA
- Removing explicit RSA cipher instantiation

What do you think?

Comment: More importantly, why do you want to use an RSA cipher together with an `InputStream`? RSA is not fit for encrypting / decrypting streams of data. This issue could be some kind of change to support authenticated ciphers. Authenticated ciphers don't play nice with input streams and IMHO use a botched API. After reading the data from a stream it may be required to verify the authentication tag and/or padding. That would be a good reason to call `doFinal`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you. It is just a byte-stream with the encrypted secret key for AES so it is not a problem of the amount of data. But the implication might be correct. There is no use for a stream when there only is one "word" to decrypt. I update the answer with some test code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there were some changes for the default security providers of android.

```
Cipher        c;
Provider      p;
StringBuilder bldr;

c    = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
p    = cipher.getProvider();
bldr = new StringBuilder();

bldr.append(_p.getName())
  .append(" ").append(_p.getVersion())
  .append(" (").append(_p.getInfo()).append(")");
Log.i("test", bldr.toString());
```

It seems to use a version of BouncyCastle on all tested Android versions (I tested down to 2.3):

- **Android 5**:
  `BC 1.5 (BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.50)`
- **Android 6**:
  `BC 1.52 (BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.52)`

However, something changed with the "explicit" cipher:

```
c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

- **Android 4.1.2**:
  `BC 1.46 (BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.46)`
- **Android 4.4.2**:
  `AndroidOpenSSL 1.0 (Android's OpenSSL-backed security provider)`
- **Android 5.1.1**:
  `AndroidOpenSSL 1.0 (Android's OpenSSL-backed security provider)`
- **Android 6.0.1**:
  `AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround 1.0 (Android KeyStore security provider to work around Bouncy Castle)`

So the final solution is setting the provider explicitly to BouncyCastle which is working on all tested android versions, even with streaming:

```
Provider p;
Cipher   c;

p = Security.getProvider("BC");
c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", p);
```

Comment: Note that setting provider explicitly is deprecated now: "The BC provider is deprecated and when targetSdkVersion is moved to P this method will throw a NoSuchAlgorithmException. To fix this you should stop specifying a provider and use the default implementation less..." says Android Studio